# change object position for a keyframe

Tags: keyframes

When I tried adding keyframes from my second object I got this result:

[image]
[Result](https://media.giphy.com/media/KFPyb0KP1lBB2ivJGR/giphy.gif)

is there any way I can change specific keyframes to match the animation?

Comment: Please use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: hard to understand what's your problem, maybe give more explanations?

Comment: @moonboots, when I combined two animations you could see that their positions are different and not in the same location, the first part of the animation, is at the end of the wall while the second part of it is in the middle of the wall and goes inside a wall, so my question is there a way to change the XYZ and the location of the second part animation only?

Comment: if it's for a movie (and not a game, which I guess would make the things a bit more complicate) you can select the animation, open the Graph Editor, select the X Location curve only, and move it so that it puts the character at the exact position you want. Maybe before that keep a copy of the original animation.

Comment: you can also move the armature (in Object mode) to the position where the second animation is supposed to begin, in that case create a first keyframe for your first animation, a second at the same position for the last frame of this first animation, and a new keyframe at the new position for the beginning of the second animation

Comment: it also depends what you mean by combining animations, do you use the NLA to put the second animation after the first one or have you copied pasted an animation into another so that there's only one? Maybe share the file (delete the mesh and keep only the armature)

Comment: @moonboots I copied pasted an animation into another.

Comment: oh ok then go in the Graph Editor, lock all the tracks except the X Location, select the second part of the X Location curve, when the second part of the animation begins, and move it so that your character moves on the X axis until where it is supposed to be. Tell me if you understand

Comment: @moonboots I'm pretty new to blender so I don't really understand what you mean, is there any video that could help me?

Comment: I'm going to answer more in detail

Comment: @moonboots Yes, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pasted an armature animation (series of bones keyframes) after another one. But when it plays, your bones jump from their position at the end of animation 1 to their position at the beginning of animation 2. Like that:

[image]

As we can see your bones are not at the good position on the X axis at the beginning of the second part of the animation. The simplest solution to fix this is to use the *Graph Editor*:

Select the root bone of your armature (the bone that is the parent of the bones hierarchy), if you don't have any, select all the bones. Open the *Graph Editor*, enable the *Only Include Channels Relating to Selected Object* (arrow icon) so that you only see the curve of the selected bone(s), lock all the tracks (padlock icon) except the *X Location* one.

On the horizontal axis you have the timeline in frames, on the vertical axis you have the position of the bone on the X axis. As you can see in my screenshot the *X Location* curve clearly shows the jump at frame 21 that makes the bone go back far from its position at frame 20.

With <kbd>B</kbd> (box select) select all the curve vertices on the right of this frame (frame 21 to 40 in my example), and move down so that it aligns with the previous position (position of frame 20 in my example). Now the armature has moved on the X axis at the good position.

[image]

Comment: how can I move more than 1? After I select with Box select and try to move it selects one and doesn't move the others.
Nevermind, I was just dumb, thanks for helping!

Comment: so did you succeed? I don't know what was your problem, with box select you can select several vertices, you can also put your green line at the position where you want your selection to begin, then put your cursor on the right of the green line, then ctrl left click, it will select everything on the right of the line

Comment: Not really I get some weird thing which I don't know how to do the same thing you did, my graph looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/n1fehBa)

Comment: you can zoom out in the vertical axis, I don't know what's the common key shortcut though, but anyway it should work the way I've described, maybe follow some tutorials about the Graph Editor, but also about Dopesheet, animation, NLA, etc...